# como leer de un txt generado de unos entry box y pararse en cada linea de el

Tags: python, tkinter, txt

supongamos que tenemos este codigo

```
import tkinter as tk


def send_data():
    correo_info = correo.get()
    password_info = password.get()
    newfile = open("clientes.txt", "a")
    newfile.write(correo_info)
    newfile.write("\t")
    newfile.write(password_info)
    newfile.write("\n")
    newfile.close()
    textocorreo.delete(0,  tk.END)
    textopass.delete(0, tk.END)

raiz = tk.Tk()
raiz.title("hola mundo")
#raiz.iconbitmap("F:\eglog\Proyectos\Panama\Archivos py\Con-Exceptions\TKINTER\imagenes\images.ico")
raiz.geometry("1000x850")
raiz.config(bg="gray")
raiz.config(bd="30")
raiz.config(relief="groove")
miframe = tk.Frame(raiz, bg="white", width="1000", height="650")
miframe.pack(fill="both", expand="True")
correo = tk.StringVar(raiz)
password = tk.StringVar(raiz)

nombrelable = tk.Label(miframe, text="Cuenta de Correo:", font=16)
nombrelable.grid(row=1, column=0)
passlabel = tk.Label(miframe, text ="Contraseña:", font=(16))
passlabel.grid(row=2, column=0)
textocorreo= tk.Entry(miframe, width="30", textvariable=correo)
textocorreo.grid(row=1, column=1)
textopass= tk.Entry(miframe, width="30", textvariable=password)
textopass.grid(row=2, column=1)
ingresarboton = tk.Button(miframe, text="Ingresar", command=send_data)
ingresarboton.grid(row=11, column=1)

raiz.mainloop()
```

como aprecian este codigo genera un guardado de datos cada ves que pulsas el boton,,cabe mencionar que los datos de correo y password se guardan en la misma linea del txt separados por ("\t"),es decir un espacio de tabulador,al pulsar nuevamente el boton se genera otra linea y vuelve a guardar dichos datos separados de igual manera ,vea la fig[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces lo que quiero como leer esos datos indistintamentes,,por ejemplo quiero leer la palabra margarita,o paco,o marlon@gmail.com,resumiendo leer indistintamente el contenido de ese txt sabiendo que los datos de la misma linea estan reparados por un espacio de tabulador,,saludos

Answer (score 0):

Para cargar los datos basta con que leas el archivo linea a linea y uses `str.split` para separar por `\t`, por ejemplo:

```
def cargar_clientes():
    clientes = []
    with open("clientes.txt",  "a+") as file:
        file.seek(0)
        clientes = [line.rstrip().split("\t") for line in file]
    return clientes

clientes = cargar_clientes()
print(clientes)
```

La salida es una lista, de la forma:

```
[['alejandro@gmail.com', 'alejandro'],
 ['marlon@gmail.com', 'marlon'],
 ...
]
```

o una lista vacía si no hay datos.

Ten en cuenta que guardar contraseñas en un archivo de texto plano es muy mala idea si tu aplicación va a tener un uso serio.

Comment: gracias pero me parece que no me entendiste yo no quiero leer el contido del txt leina por linea ,,yo kiero leer  una palabra indistintamente,,por ejmplo quiero leer pasword marlon,pero ese solo,,o el correo paco @gamil.com pero ese solo

Comment: Tienes de todas formas que iterar (o leer el archivo al completo) linea a linea hasta encontrar esa linea exactamente como hago yo, o usar otro sistema menos básico de persistencia, como una base de datos...